# Drupal Youtube feed in Views, only first video works- the rest do not?

Tags: drupal, youtube-api, drupal-views, drupal-feeds

I am using the Feeds and Mediafront, and Media module and emfield. I set up the feed importer to map in the Youtube RSS and I mapped the url to a embedded media field. Then I created a new View to display all the videos from the RSS. But only the first video on the View page will work, the rest are blank empty video players? But if I click on each title. The video is displayed on the node page. The View is the problem. is it DOM or view cache? Why is only the very first video working?
Any suggesting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any Javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a generic error & not too easy to debug. Is the issue reproducible with different video ordering, or entirely different videos? May possibly be an issue with an old version of jQuery that isn't supported... possibly. Do you have the jQuery update module enabled? If not, could be the first one to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
In Drupal Views set whatever your media field is to the formatter called 'Rendered file', not mediafront or media player. Then the view will display all of the rss feeds and playable videos. I also just installed the jQuery update module. But the problem was the wrong formatter. In Drupal6 the formatter i used was "lightbox video". I feel like i have to relearn everything in Drupal7. Just like if you are very good at photohop V6 or Flash V4. Then they come out with the new version and I feel lost! I know its all about improving the product but its tough to relearn a different way of doing what you are used to doing.

Comment: Glad you fixed your issue- sorry I couldn't be more help! I know what you mean about relearning everything, but the comments in the API docs are often really useful for giving D6->D7 help. D7 is vastly superior to D6 though and definitely worth it :)